# JQuery/Ajax/PHP cross call gives undefined when loading content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

We need to load content from another page in to our own page for school trough the servers. No idea how to get further. It never loads content only the word 'undefined'.

Thanks in advance!

This is how for i got:

```
        <script>
        var jQitems = {};

            var htmlString = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: "crosscall/crosscall.php",
        data: {url: "http://www.beerpulse.com"},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {


            //jQitems.attr = {}; == jQitems['attr'];
            //jQitems.attr.title = ".attr()";


$(data).find(".hentry").each(function(){
                console.log(this);
                var $el = $(this);
                var abbr = $el.attr('data-slug');
                jQitems[abbr] = {};
                var entry = {};
                jQitems[abbr].image = $el.find('.hentry a img.excerpt_thumb wp-post-image').html();
                jQitems[abbr].title = $el.find('.excerpt-title').html();
                jQitems[abbr].description = $el.find('div.entry-summary').filter('div.entry-meta').html();
                htmlString += '<div class="content">'; 
                htmlString += '<img class="afbeelding src="' + jQitems[abbr].image + '">';
                htmlString += '<p class="tekst">';
                htmlString += jQitems[abbr].description + '</p></div>';

                /*$.ajax({
                    url: "crosscall/crosscall.php",
                    data: {url: "http://www.beerpulse.com/" + abbr},
                    type: "POST",
                    success: onDetailSuccess

                });*/
            });
            $('.wrapper').append(htmlString);

        }              
    });

            function onDetailSuccess(data) 
                {
                    var abbr = $(data).find('.abbr'); //verander selectie
                    jQitems[abbr].description = $(data).find('.entry-summary'); //verander selectie

                    var htmlString = '';
                    $.each(jQitems, function(index, item){
                        //...
                    });
                    $('div#result').append(htmlString);
                }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: Sorry it is rather hard for me to explain in proper English.
We need to use an existing web page and take content out of this and put this in our website. We gotta do this with a PHP script we got from our teacher. We need to make our own JS/JQuery/Ajax script so the content appears on my personal website. I manage to select the different <div> i want and let them appear in my console, but on my site they simply appear as the word 'undefined'. This is my problem.

I hope this helped a bid?

Comment: Would the [jQuery load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) work for you?

    `$('#result').load('crosscall/crosscall.php?url=http://www.beerpulse.com', function(data) {
        console.log('#result should now have whatever crosscall.php displayed');
    });`

I don't know what your PHP script displays, but you should be able to do any formatting in PHP.